# Ansible create reusable dynamic environment variable inside a task

Tags: bash, ansible

Is it possible to set a reusable **dynamic** environment variable during task execution in Ansible?
Like so:

```
---
- name: grab secret from unexposed port 1234
  raw: SECRET=$(curl --silent http://127.0.0.1:1234/secret)
- name: use secret for something
  raw: echo $SECRET
```

Comment: And when do you expect the variable to be resolved?

Comment: The cron module was a poor example here. I updated the question to be more simple.

Comment: No need for an environment variable here.

Comment: But is it possible?

Comment: It depends. Are you interested in yes/no answer? That's not what SO is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansible is executing a subshell for each separate command. You can't set a variable in the parent process from a subshell.

Don't use `raw`. If you absolutely must use `raw`, try to rethink.
If you still must, it still creates a subshell and isn't going to do what you want.

You need to move the value to the ansible parent process.

```
- command: curl --silent http://127.0.0.1:1234/secret
  register: tmpvar

# pull just the bit you want - tmpvar has lots of extraneous stuff
- set_fact:
    SECRET: "{{ tmpvar.stdout }}"

- shell: |
    SECRET="{{ SECRET }}"
    echo $SECRET
```

Comment: No real need for the shell assignment either, but thought it might matter for what you are trying to do. ~shrug~